# Material UI - body scroll locked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

During my running project, I was using Material UI. I was designing a dashboard for my site.
Then **I noticed that my scroll bar was being blocked while every time I opened the menu list.**
Just like the following image:

[image]
[image]

I copied this code from [MaterialUI official webiste](https://mui.com/components/app-bar/#main-content). I still its blocking the scroll bar. Where is the code:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';

const pages = ['Products', 'Pricing', 'Blog'];
const settings = ['Profile', 'Account', 'Dashboard', 'Logout'];

const ResponsiveAppBar = () => {
  const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);

  const handleOpenNavMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleOpenUserMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElNav(null);
  };

  const handleCloseUserMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="div"
            sx={{ mr: 2, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}
          >
            LOGO
          </Typography>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' } }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls="menu-appbar"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElNav}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
              onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' },
              }}
            >
              {pages.map((page) => (
                <MenuItem key={page} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{page}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="div"
            sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' } }}
          >
            LOGO
          </Typography>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
            {pages.map((page) => (
              <Button
                key={page}
                onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                sx={{ my: 2, color: 'white', display: 'block' }}
              >
                {page}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </Box>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
            <Tooltip title="Open settings">
              <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
                <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            <Menu
              sx={{ mt: '45px' }}
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElUser}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
              onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
            >
              {settings.map((setting) => (
                <MenuItem key={setting} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{setting}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
};
export default ResponsiveAppBar;
```

**What I have to do to fix this bug?**

Answer (score 5):

The issue is from the `Menu` component, when it is open it styles the body element overflow to hidden.

To stop that, Set the disableScrollLock prop to true.

```
<Menu
  ...others
  disableScrollLock={true}
>

</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a problem with your AppBar as much as your other code, which we cannot see.

But I'm guessing you have something like this:

```
export default function App(){
    return (
      <div className="root">
        <ResponsiveAppBar />
        <div className="image-background-1">
          <h1>Some text</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="image-background-2">
          <h1>Some text</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="image-background-3">
          <h1>Some text</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
         
    )
}
```

In this scenario, the whole "root" div is scrolling, but in your design we really just want to scroll through the `div`s with the image background.

To fix this, wrap those divs in a div that has `overflow-y: scroll`:

```
export default function App(){
    return (
      <div className="root">
        <ResponsiveAppBar />
        <div style={{overflowY: "scroll"}}>
            <div className="image-background-1">
              <h1>Some text</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="image-background-2">
              <h1>Some text</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="image-background-3">
              <h1>Some text</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
         
    )
}
```

You might need to set `overflow: "hidden"` on the `root` div as well.